PDF blank in ngx-extended-pdf-viewer for Japanese
My application uses ngx-extended-pdf-viewer to display PDFs. It works fine for all other languages but if I upload a PDF with Japanese characters, it loads a blank page.
pdfviewer.component.html
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer #pdfViewer [zoom] = "'page-width'" [height]="'100%'" [src]="pdfSrc" 
[showPrintButton]="false" 
[customToolbar]="additionalButtons" 
[enablePinchOnMobile]="true" 
[showBookmarkButton]="false" 
[showOpenFileButton]="false" 
[showFindButton]="false" 
[showBorders]="false" 
[showScrollingButton]="false"
[showSpreadButton]="false" 
[page]="page" (pagesLoaded)="pagesLoaded($event)" [handTool]="false" theme="dark" useBrowserLocale="true" height="85vh" ></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>

<ng-template #additionalButtons>
    <div id="toolbarViewer">
      <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
        <pdf-paging-area *ngIf ="!mobileView"></pdf-paging-area>
        <pdf-page-number *ngIf ="mobileView" id="pageNumber"  ></pdf-page-number>
      </div>
      <pdf-zoom-toolbar *ngIf ="!mobileView"></pdf-zoom-toolbar>
      <div *ngIf ="mobileView" id="toolbarViewerMiddle">
            
            <pdf-zoom-out id="zoomOut"></pdf-zoom-out>
            <pdf-zoom-in id="zoomIn"></pdf-zoom-in>
      </div>
      <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
        <pdf-download id="download"> </pdf-download>
        <pdf-toggle-secondary-toolbar>
                <div class="secondaryToolbar hidden doorHangerRight" id="secondaryToolbar"  >
                                <button title="Download" id="secondaryDownload"  ></button>
                                <button title="Go to First Page" id="firstPage"  ></button>
                                <button title="Go to Last Page" id="lastPage"  ></button>
                                <button title="Rotate Clockwise" id="pageRotateCw"  ></button>
                                <button title="Rotate Counterclockwise" id="pageRotateCcw"  ></button>
                                <button title="Document Properties…" id="documentProperties"  ></button>
                </div>   
        </pdf-toggle-secondary-toolbar>
      </div>
     </div>

  </ng-template>

I went through the details of this package on npmjs website but couldn't find anything related to my issue. The PDF is not corrupted as it opens fine in the browser. The application uses Angular 8 and latest version of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.

I did try uploading on extended-pdf-viewer demo online, it works fine there.
